# How do I test geolocation javascripts?

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I'm currently working on some geolocation javascripts, but am unable to test and debug them properly: My desktop machine (Running Windows, with Chrome 5 or Firefox 3) doesn't have location information and my mobile devices don't feature any debugging capabilities.

How can I test geolocation scripts? Is there a tool which will fake a GPS sensor?

Comment: I found two Firefox add-ons (Geolocater and Geolocation) so far, but the two don't seem to be working. There are no Chrome extensions currently aviable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Firefox, it's possible to switch the default Geolocation provider (Google) to a manually entered source.

[Fake your geolocation in Firefox 3.5](http://pugio.net/2009/07/fake-your-geolocation-in-firef.html)

> All you need for faking is a text file (eg. `/home/username/.mynewlocation.txt`) somewhere on your computer with the following content:
>    `{"location":{"latitude":50.941863,"longitude":6.958374, "accuracy":20.0}}`
>
> The path in Firefox to this file is:
>   `file://home/username/.mynewlocation.txt`
>
> Type about:config in your location bar, confirm the warning, search for geo.wifi.url, and replace the old url (`https://www.google.com/loc/json`) with your new one from above. Restart firefox, enjoy your new location :-)

And there's [a similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800990/geolocation-provider-for-firefox-that-allows-manual-input) with a number of good answers as well.

Answer (score 5):

In chrome, you can now use the [manual geolocation](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mfodligkojepnddfhkbkodbamcagfhlo) chrome extension to set your location manually.

Answer (score 3):

[Chrome now (tested in version 25) supports Geolocation spoofing via Developer Tools](http://www.labnol.org/internet/geo-location/27878/)

Answer (score 0):

the [geo-location-javascript](http://code.google.com/p/geo-location-javascript/) library contains a component for simulating locations, you simply add them with:

```
locations=new Array();
locations.push({ coords:{latitude:41.39985,longitude:2.19610},duration:5000 });
locations.push({ coords:{latitude:41.40,longitude:2.197},duration:5000 });
```

and the you initialize the component. look under simulation on the homepage

Answer (score 0):

If the location you want to test is based on geolocation API in HTML5, you can fake the location by this extension.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/change-geolocation/njjpmclekpigefnogajiknnheheacoaj?hl=ja