# Testing Geo Location via Watir?

Tags: ruby, testing, geolocation, watir

I'm wanting to create Watir tests for my application which uses data taken from Geo Location. However I want the tests to be able to change the Geo location data so the application believes it is reviving new information.

Is it possible to fake geo-location using Watir? And how?

Comment: If you were to manually execute the test, how would you fake the geo-location?

Comment: @JustinKo have a browser widget in Chrome, called Ripple and it fakes the geo-location. But I'm not too sure how.

Answer (score 1):

For Firefox, you can fake your loction by setting `geo.wifi.url` option. See [Geolocation provider for Firefox that allows manual input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800990/geolocation-provider-for-firefox-that-allows-manual-input) for details.

Therefore, it should be OK to use Watir's Firefox driver [setting that option](http://watirwebdriver.com/firefox/) and fake a location.

Comment: This is useful but I need to handle more than just firefox. +1 for the info.